# not able to execute vba code-object error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create macro to copy data from multiple sheets to single sheet, data which is updated frequently on each sheets and looking to avoid repetition in data copy if every time I run macro.

I have written below code but its throwing runtime error, please help to solve this error, so I can complete my project.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Lastrow As Long, erow As Long, totalSheets As Long

totalSheets = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To totalSheets

    If Worksheets(i).Name <> "Summary" Then

        Lastrow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 5 To Lastrow

             Worksheets(i).Activate

             Worksheets(i).Cells(i, 1).Copy
             erow = Summary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

             Worksheets(i).Paste Destination = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(erow, 2)

             Worksheets(i).Cells(i, 2).Copy
             Worksheets(i).Paste Destination = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(erow, 3)


             Worksheets(i).Cells(i, 11).Copy
             Worksheets(i).Paste Destination = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(erow, 4)

         Next

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thanks alot @peh for quick help.But everyday i need to enter data on other sheets and i want to copy new data entered on multiple sheets in Summary sheet on clicking the button.Suggest if any changes can be done in similar code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is an easy way accomplish your goal:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, erow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet

    Set wsSummary = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        With Worksheets(i)

            If .Name <> "Summary" Then

                Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                For j = 5 To Lastrow

                    erow = wsSummary.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'make usre that column A has data.

                    .Cells(j, 1).Copy wsSummary.Cells(erow, 2) 'Have in mind that the specific copy - paste method also copy formats.

                    .Cells(j, 2).Copy wsSummary.Cells(erow, 3)

                    .Cells(j, 11).Copy wsSummary.Cells(erow, 4)

                 Next

            End If

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot this code too worked effortlessly. But everyday i need to enter data on other sheets and i want to copy new data entered on multiple sheets in Summary sheet on clicking the button.Suggest if any changes can be done in similar code

Comment: one possible solution is to mark the last row after the code finish and the next time you run the code to start from the next line.